# Is there any way I can create a WSDL file from WCF Service Application?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

Im creating a WCF Service application, I dnt want to give the URL to the client use rather I need to give a Single WSDL file.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 6):

svcutil will generate its if you need it to. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702581.aspx for details.

Comment: Thank you scmccart, I referred you answer and used "svcutil.exe Contracts.dll" to create WSDL. it has created 5 files not a single WSDL. I need a single WSDL.

I am new to WCF, it anything wrong pardon me!!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe there is a way to stop it from generating separate xsd files. You can probably merge the files by hand or find a tool to do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

C:>svcutil.exe /t:metadata http:/localhost:1234/testservice.svc?singleWsdl

Answer (score 0):

Use disco.exe http:///service.svc
Will be generate .disco, .wsdl and .xsd (optional more than one).

I think disco.exe better than svcutil.exe